# Find absolute maximum and minimum of a function with two variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, optimization

I have the function$ f(x,y)=(x+y-2)^2$

I have the constraints $0\leq x \leq 3$ and $x \leq y \leq 3$

The partial derivatives are $f_x =2(x+y-2)$ and $f_y =2(x+y-2)$

So the stationary points in the domain are (0,2) and (1,1)

Now if I look at the second partial derivative it isn't helpful at $f_{xx} =2 f_{yy}=2$ and $f_{xy} =2$

How can I find the absolute maximum and minimum thanks

Comment: Parametrize the boundary line segments and do one-variable calculus max/min on each, then compare boundary results with values at your interior critical points.

Comment: adding to the comment above, if things clearly appear as functions of some linear combination of coordinates, it is generally a good idea to use that basis. In this example, let $u = x+y$, $v = y-x$. You're looking for the extrema of $f(u,v) = (u-2)^2$ over the set $0 \le v \le 3, 0 \le u \le 6$, which is your standard 1-D theory, as $f$ is independent of $v$.

Comment: Also note that you haven't identified all the stationary points. Every $(x,y): x+y = 2$ is a stationary point of $f$.

Comment: i.e. she has a critical line... plotting: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot3d+%7Bx%2Cy%2C%28x%2By-2%29%5E2%7D%2C+0%3Cx%3C2%2C0%3Cy%3C2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have that all of the points $(x,y)$ with $x+y = 2$ will be critical points, not only $(1,1)$ and $(0,2)$. The function is zero at these points and $f\geq 0 $ always, so each one of them is an absolute minimum.

You can also look at $(x+y-2)^2$ with $x+y$ as a variable on its own. Given that $0\leq x\leq y \leq 3$, its greater value when $x=y=3$, so $(3, 3)$ is the maximum point with $f(3,3) = 16 $.